# Tables not generated using Derby and OpenJPA

Tags: java, jpa, derby, openjpa, auto-generate

Tables are not generated in database even when i set attribute `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` to `create` and connection string `javax.persistence.jdbc.url` to `jdbc:derby:db;create=true`

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DataLayer"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>DataSource</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:derby:db;create=true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my testing method:

```
HashMap<String, String> jpaProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
jpaProps.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:derby:db;create=true");
jpaProps.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
jpaProps.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "create");
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DataLayer", jpaProps);
EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
EntityPerson person = new EntityPerson();
person.setAge(25);
person.setName("Michael Pear");
manager.getTransaction().begin();
manager.persist(person); 
manager.getTransaction().commit(); //<- Exception here saying EntityPerson Table does not exist.
```

As you can see, I also tried to override properties by supplying them to `createEntityManagerFactory` method.

My EntityPerson class:

```
@Entity
public class EntityPerson
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    private int age;
    
    ... getters and setters
}
```

Also tried excplicitly define Table name and Entity name with annotations:

```
@Entity(name = "EntityPerson")
@Table(name = "EntityPerson")
```

How to generate tables in db by annotated classes by startup of a program (during runtime)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java EE can discover entities automatically, but as i am building desktop application aka. using Java SE, i needed to mention entities in persistence-unit in persistence.xml file like so:

```
<class>entities.EntityPerson</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You configured a  `<non-jta-data-source>DataSource</non-jta-data-source>`, JPA will try to load data source from this configured DataSource.
2. Try to use a relative path(`./`) or `/xxx` to store the temporary data when using an embedded db.

I am not sure these resolved your problems, the `create` value in the `persistence.xml` is ok.

[Eclipse cargotrakcer](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/) is the official reference application, in the [Java EE 7](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/cargotracker/releases) which used a derby config for GF/Payara. In the latest Jakarta EE 8, it switched to use a custom DataSource.

Comment: Adding <class>entities.EntityPerson</class> to persistence.xml fix my issue, but should not be jpa able to generate tables from @Entity annotations? I tought i do not have to mention all classes in persistence.xml. I am creating desktop application which will use db via jpa, data will be persistent and not temporary. I want db to be in same folder as application, so not using relative path should not be a problem, right?

Comment: Java EE is ok for discovering the entities automatically, but for SE, you could have to add the classes manually. Spring has deep envelope with JPA to make it easy to use like in a Java EE containers.

Comment: It is a desktop application, not sure what UI you are using, Swing or JavaFX? I think you can also add an IOC container, such as Spring, or CDI/Weld, or Guice, etc.

Comment: Will be using JavaFX. What would be the advantage to add such IOC container?

Comment: Like in the backend, you can declare the [Java FX `Controller` class](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker-regapp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/cargotrakcer/regapp/ui/HandlingReportController.java) as a bean, and inject other services directly. Check my [CDI/Java FX example](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker-regapp)(I am a newbie of Java FX).

Comment: Spring/Java FX example, https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/11/tutorial-reactive-spring-boot-a-javafx-spring-boot-application/